# how to run a conda environment based script via rc.local

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, conda

I have a lengthy python scrip `program.py` sitting inside my downloads folder. I am able to run this script only after activating my specific conda environment using `source /home/machineX/miniconda3/bin/activate my_env`. I have written the below bash script `trigger.sh` to activate my conda environment and run my python script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/machineX/Downloads/
source /home/machineX/miniconda3/bin/activate my_env
python /home/machineX/Downloads/program.py
```

I am running my script using the following command `source /home/machineX/trigger.sh`

Normally when I run it, first I activate my conda environment conda activate the_env and then run it by writing python program.py in my bash terminal.

My goal is to run my `program.py` at the powering on of the machine. So I am trying to execute `trigger.sh` via `rc.local`. So I added the following before `exit 0` in my `etc/rc.local`

```
su machineX -c '/home/machineX/trigger.sh'
```

Everything looks alright, my `rc.local` runs all types of bash scripts using the above line. But it just gives up at conda based script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem. It was a very simple fix but took me 3 hours to figure out. This is a good lesson for anyone who is working with conda and rc.local

I edited my `trigger.sh` script to a line to execute conda.sh before activating my conda environment.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/machineX/Downloads/
#****** the new special line *******
source /home/machineX/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
#***********************************
source /home/machineX/miniconda3/bin/activate my_env
python /home/machineX/Downloads/program.py
```